# HTML/Bootstrap - Aligning Image on corner of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For the fast few hours I have been trying to figure how to do this with Bootstrap and HTML. I want to align the image on the corner of the screen but it seems like it doesnt want to work my way. I don't have any CSS code so thats why I'm trying to figure out how to do it. I have tried the pull classes but they also seem to not help either.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="shared">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>some stuff</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="img/pexels-photo-325223.jpeg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example of what I want, see the space on the right? I want to fill it by moving the image on the side.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Goe.png)

I'd appreciate anyone who can help me out :)!

Comment: The `pull-right` class works perfectly fine. Are you setting it on the image itself?

Comment: can you share the working `fiddle`. The image you showed is not a good support. Better share the actual design you have.

Comment: `pull-right` moves it to the right a little bit more, but still a gap still there.

Comment: @DeepakYadav http://imgur.com/a/GRTGS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a `.row` around your columns:

```
<div class="shared">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>some stuff</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="img/pexels-photo-325223.jpeg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next, you need to either set the image as inline-block and text-align the column right, or set the image to display block and float right.

If you can only use Bootstrap's built-in rules, set `class="pull-right"` on the image.

Comment: Columns have a gutter on the right and left. Is that the gap you're referring to?

Comment: I believe so, check this image out: http://i.imgur.com/gGtUSmN.png Thats a section on the website, and I want to the image on the right to fill the gap up

Comment: I'm on my phone at the moment, but to fill the entire screen, your row needs to be fluid, and you will need to set the right margin of the image to a negative value, typically -15px to offset the column gutter.

Comment: You'll also want to remove the container div if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Removing the container div puts the image off the screen just a little bit. Instead I did what you said before and add the negative margin and put it in a container-fluid but now it seems the image column is smaller than the left column. http://i.imgur.com/0MW0Fsv.png

Comment: Is your image set to be responsive? If not, and it's not equal to the width of the column, it will appear shorter.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:** You can use `text-right` on col-md-6.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="shared">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x400/000/fff">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** You can use pull-right on col-md-6

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="shared">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x400/000/fff">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 3:** For the requiremnt add a class nopadding + text-right and a line of custom css to achieve your result.

```css
.shared .nopadding{ padding:0px !important}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="shared ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 nopadding text-right">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x400/000/fff">
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bro you still you watching DBz...? @Sahil Dhir

Comment: Updated answer : Check solution 3 @Avi24

Comment: it seems to work, but the columns aren't equal for some reason. http://i.imgur.com/DXAFIt4.png the image has a lower width even though i have width: 100%; in my CSS for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pull-right` class on image tag like below.

```
<div class="shared">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>some stuff</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="pull-right" src="img/pexels-photo-325223.jpeg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will push your image to the right.

Think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="shared">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>some stuff</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                <img src="img/pexels-photo-325223.jpeg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```